# What is the point of the reassignment of the youHit variable in this simple task?

Tags: javascript

```
var slaying = true;

var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

var totalDamage = 0;


while (slaying) {

    if (youHit) {
        console.log("Congrats you hit the dragon!");
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;

        if(totalDamage >= 4) {
//This one right here.....
            youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        };

        }else { 
            console.log("The dragon beat you boyeeeeee");
            };
```

I was given this as an assignment and I know what I am doing because this is my third simple class. However, I know there must be a point to reassigning the you Hit class but I don't see it. Can someone please explain the purpose?

Comment: If it weren't re-assigned you'd never change whether you were hit or not as it would always be the same while slaying.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I would just like to say `youHit` is not a class, it's a variable. EcmaScript 5 (common JavaScript) doesn't have classes.

Comment: right yea whoops just typed that in wrong is all. Too used to css.lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to say that it's meaningless besides the +1 part. Adding +1 will make that always return 1 or higher, so not 0, not false. Once you have dealt more than 4 damage to the dragon, he is now too weak to dodge any attacks made on him during that slaying session :) Why is it not youHit = 1; ? No clue.

Answer (score 0):

`youHit` is checked inside the loop. The reassignment you're interested in will alter the behaviour of the next iteration of the loop: it'll check the new value of `youHit` when it gets to `if (youHit)` again.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is to simulate the next hit in terms of damage to the dragon. However, `youHit` will never go negative as `Math.random()` returns a value between 0 and 1 (that is inclusive of 0 and exclusive of 1 per MDN).

If `youHit` where to go negative, the `if (youHit)` would be false and the dragon would win. The `while` loop keeps going until the fight is over. We can't see all the code but the solution might be to change `youHit` to potentially be negative.

I would do that like so:

```
(Math.random() - 0.5) * 5
```

I'm not certain the distribute will be potentially 50% negative and 50% positive but close enough for our purposes here.

Comment: Well I do have a Math.floor just before that so if it is less than 0.5 it will be rounded down to 0 which is false also......I think you were looking at damageThisRound also but it's all good man.Thanks for responding.

Comment: @KingBumWorthyPHPHacktivist Yes but then you +1 it so it won't go down to 0.